# Scanner nextLine() issues

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I've been working on a programming assignment that acts as a Scrabble dictionary for a while now. The program takes input from the user and outputs a file with a list of words, depending on what the user requests from a menu. The problem I've been having has to do with Scanner.nextLine().

I'm not aexactly sure why, but for some reason I have to press enter once sometimes before my code will take my input and store it as the variable. Essentially, I end up entering the input twice. I tried inserting Scanner.nextLine() around the code to "take up" the empty enter/spaces but it doesnt work, and I have to press enter multiple times to get it to process what I want.

Does anybody have any suggestions? I'd appreciate any and all help.

Here is a bit of the code:

```
System.out.println("Enter the length of the word you are" + " searching for.");
int n = -1;
while(!(n >=0)) {
    if(in.hasNextInt())
        n = in.nextInt();
    else {
        System.out.println("You have not entered a valid number. 
                            Please enter a real number this  time.");
        in.nextLine();
    }   
}
in.nextLine();
System.out.println("Enter the first letter of the words" + " you are searching for.");
String firstLetter = "";
while(!(firstLetter.length() == 1)) {
    if(in.nextLine().length() > 1) {
        System.out.println("You have not entered a valid letter. 
                            Please press enter and enter only one real letter.");
    } 
    else if(in.hasNextInt()) {
        System.out.println("Do not enter a number. Please enter one real letter.");
    }
    else {
        in.nextLine();
        firstLetter = in.nextLine();
        break;
    }
}
```

At the end of this, I have to press enter once and then input to get it to store anything in the variable firstLetter. I assume it has something to do with the nature of nextLine(), as the conditions using nextInt() give no issues.

Comment: If you expect people to volunteer their time to help you solve your problems, you should at least make the effort to format your code correctly.

Comment: Thanks, I'm sorry dude, I tabbed it like eight times and it still wouldn't format. Control+K did jack as well. Viva la vendetta though.

Comment: Tabs are not your friend :) Next time, try to use just spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're overcompensating with too many `nextLine`s. You may want to do that *once* to clear the line after the int is inputted, for example, to clear the newline, but the second time here just absorbs an extra line of input:

```
System.out.println("You have not entered a valid number. Please enter a real number this time.");
            in.nextLine();//first time
            }   
        }
        in.nextLine();//this second time is unnecessary.
```

The same thing happens with your duplicate uses here:

```
in.nextLine();
firstLetter = in.nextLine();
break;
```

You should only add an extra `in.nextLine()` immediately between inputting `nextSOMETHINGELSE()` and another `nextLine()`.

EDIT:

Additionally, note that *whenever you call `in.nextLine()`*, you are absorbing a line of input. For example, this line should be fixed:

```
        if(in.nextLine().length() > 1){
```

because it reads in a line, **using it up,** and then checks whether that (now used-up) line is long enough.

Comment: Thanks, I was just randomly putting those in to see if it would help (great technique, I know). Once I take all of those out though, the program still makes me input three times before it assigns my input to the variable and closes out of the loop.

Comment: Ouu!! Ok, so I should probably change my condition. No idea what I should change it too, though.

Comment: maybe you could create a `String s;` on a previous line and then use (s=in.nextLine()).length() thus saving the `in.nextLine()` in `s` and then you could use `s` to access that line of input in future operations.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate all of your suggestions, but I'm not sure I completely understand this last comment. I tried storing the length of nextLine in s as an int, but it doesn't do much. Could you clarify what you meant a little further? (Sorry!)

Comment: try replacing the if statement innards with `(s=in.nextLine()).length()>1` and then all the later uses of `in.nextLine()` with `s`. (make sure you define `String s;` beforehand)

Answer (score 3):

It's because you're using both nextLine() and nextInt(), what's going on is that nextLine() is searching for a new line (enter) and nextInt will automatically stop the search if any integer is typed through System.in.

Rule of thumb: Just use Scanner.nextLine() for your input, then convert your string from Scanner.nextLine() accordingly through Integer.parseInt(string), etc.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - I had this issue before, that's what the in.nextLine() between the loops was for. I changed it to parse to an Int, but I still have to enter my inputs two or three times before the program recognizes it and assigns it to the variable, and closes out of the loop.

Comment: It's in the beginning where you're just calling in.nextLine(). You're going to press enter but not getting anything because you're not storing the string in.nextLine() is returning.